# is it possible to run pytest coverage report only for modified files

Tags: python, pytest, code-coverage

Is it possible to run coverage report for modified or newly added python files only.

Suppose I have updated 2 files in repo and added one file, Now i want to run code coverage report for the file which are added or modified.